# Leaflet map breaks after flyTo if zoom in is called

Tags: drupal-7, leaflet

As the title states, I have a Leaflet (version 1.02) map that breaks if I try to zoom in after calling a flyTo() action. Oddly, if I zoom out first, I can then zoom freely, in or out without the map breaking. Panning also works after the flyTo(), but zooming in will still break the map unless I first call a zoomOut action.

I am not at max zoom, and this happens in multiple maps with different sets of markers. If, at zoomend of the flyTo(), I setZoom at the current level, I can then zoom freely, in or out, but this causes the map to flicker after the flyTo() and is very unappealing.

Any thoughts about this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will have to be more specific about your environment (a link would be ideal). From a leaflet standpoint and using firefox, there is no problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/Qiqk3nB1gxG7Sp7Xfd4r?p=preview

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Here's a link to my test page. The map is down the page. If you click on any of the numbered links, let the animation complete, and then try and zoom in you'll see it happen. http://test.brendanryandesign.com/bear-glacier-iceberg-paddleboarding

Comment: And thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 3):

I also ran into that bug and I manage to find out a workaround, assuming that the 'zoom' function in 'flyTo' was somehow corrupting the following zoom in action made by clicking on the "+" icon. 
I decided to make the flyTo immediately followed by a setZoom action. Here's the code :

```
map.flyTo(latlong, zoom, {animate: true, duration: 3});
setTimeout(function(){ map.setZoom(zoom);}, 3000);
```

Options make the flyTo sequence last for 3 seconds
Next line waits 3 second, i.e. exact time for the flyTo to end end and then performs a setZoom, thus canceling any mysterious action of the flyTo that breaks the zoomIn action of the user. 
Then it works.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is somewhat old at this point, but if anyone runs into a situation where they're using leaflet with the flyTo() function and getting subsequent weird behaviour with zooming then the issue may be what format you're passing your arguments to flyTo().

Make sure the lat, lon are cast to float and zoom is cast to int. I ran into this issue and it turned out to be due to my parameters being passed in a strings. flyTo() seems to operate fine with strings as parameters but subsequent zoom operations act erratically.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. After a .flyTo() call pressing the Zoom + button caused the map to go to maximum zoom, but pressing the Zoom - first meant everything worked OK.
After reading dageshi above, that proved to be the issue.

> Make sure the lat, lon are cast to float and zoom is cast to int.

Adding a parseInt() to the value passed to .flyTo() fixed it straight away.
Thanks dageshi