# Why is MouseWheel zoomOut blocked after flyTo animation?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using a flyTo animation triggered by a button to zoom into a map. After the pan-zoom animation ends, it is impossible to *zoom out* using the mouse-wheel.

It works if I click on the basic zoom out control, it works if I test it on a touch screen. If I try to *zoom in* with the mouse-wheel, it works.

Any idea why this specific way to zoom out is blocked? The whole prototype is [here](http://od1.fr/projects/territoire_danse/iteration_5/) if you need to test it by yourself (click the big Play button to trigger the flyTo).

Comment: Works for me - I can zoom out with a mousewheel after a flyTo(), [using some example from the Leaflet github repo](https://plnkr.co/edit/9FJ4D5V5pr3QgkjGCIEZ?p=preview).

Comment: Try to make a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Hey @Nico, I found a similar question here on stackoverflow. Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51025086/5332988), maybe it fixes your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments (thanks Urknecht!), there was a similar question on stackoverflow I did not see. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40878381/leaflet-map-breaks-after-flyto-if-zoom-in-is-called/51025086#51025086) solved my problem:

> Make sure the lat, lon are cast to float and zoom is cast to int. I ran into this issue and it turned out to be due to my parameters being passed in a strings. flyTo() seems to operate fine with strings as parameters but subsequent zoom operations act erratically.